# Change output inside grid

Tags: c++

I am trying to use the following console display class to display a tic tac toe game- this is for an assignment- I was given the following code to use- 
The console displays a grid with columns marked 0-9, and shows rows marked 0-9- The console also displays random characters inside the grid- I need to change the random characters to ones that I choose- but I cannot find the part in the code that sets the space in the middle grid.

If anyone could help me pin point the part in the code that decides what is displayed in the grid, I would be very appreciative.

Note- It is necessary to change character set to (use Multi-Byte Character set) in order to see proper output from program. changer character set is under Project Properties- General - Project Defaults in Visual Studio

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <tchar.h>


    using std::cin;

    bool setxychar( int x, int y, const char* pBuf, int len )
    {
        HANDLE console_handle;
        COORD cursor_coord;
        DWORD actual=0;

        console_handle= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        cursor_coord.X=x;       // (40-(strlen(buffer)/2)); 
        cursor_coord.Y=y;

        //This would be the equivalent to gotoxy(x,y).
        if (SetConsoleCursorPosition(console_handle,cursor_coord)) 
        {
            // Look up this function in your VC++ help/index
            WriteConsole(console_handle,pBuf,len,&actual,NULL);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // setxychar()  - Overloaded
    // this method allows you to print a single character at a location
    bool setxychar( int x, int y, char Buf )
    {

        return( setxychar( x, y, &Buf, 1 ) );
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        const char graybar = '\xB2';
        char *buffer ="Tic Tac Toe";
        int x=0, y=0;
        for(x=0; x<80; x++) // vertical borders
        {
            y=0;
            setxychar(x,y,&graybar,1);
            y=23;
            setxychar(x,y,&graybar,1);
        }
        for( y=0; y<24; y++ )   // horizontal borders
        {
            x=0;
            setxychar(x,y,&graybar,1);
            x=79;
            setxychar(x,y,&graybar,1);
        }
        setxychar(3,3,' ');  // position pointer
        printf( "  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A  B C D E F\n" );
        char testchar = 0;      // A warning is put up by the compiler 
        for(y=4; y<20; y++ )    // "warning C4309: 'initializing' : truncation of constant value"
        {                       // 80 hex is the same as -128,  Hex is just easier
            setxychar(1,y,' ');  // position pointer
            printf( "%X", 16*(y-4) );
            for(x=6; x<38; x+=2)
            {
                setxychar(x,y,&testchar,1);
                testchar++;
            }
        }

        // Putting text to screen just for fun
        setxychar(52,6,buffer,(int)strlen(buffer));

        setxychar(1,22,' ');  // position pointer
        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: looks like: `char testchar = 0;` and `setxychar(x,y,&testchar,1);` and `testchar++;`

Comment: Thanks for your help- I will mark that as an answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the relevant parts are:

```
char testchar = 0;
```

and

```
setxychar(x,y,&testchar,1);
```

and

```
testchar++;
```